# How to create a clickable timestamp link on an embedded youtube video with javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, video, youtube

I would really like to have clickable time links on my website that will jump to specific times within my embedded youtube video. I know that this is possible within youtube itself (built in function on youtube where you just put the time you want in the format (0:00) and users can click it to jump to that point).

*I was wondering if it is possible to mimic this function somehow with embedded youtube videos and javascript?*

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Playback_controls

Comment: I hadn't cause I didn't even know where to begin. But I've gotten some good suggestions here to get me started. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [Youtube iFrame API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference). There is a function to get the current timestamp:

```
player.getCurrentTime():Number
```

> Returns the elapsed time in seconds since the video started playing.

```
player.getDuration():Number
```

> Returns the duration in seconds of the currently playing video. Note
>   that getDuration() will return 0 until the video's metadata is loaded,
>   which normally happens just after the video starts playing.

Use them like so:

```
ytplayer = document.getElementById("youtube_player");
ytplayer.getCurrentTime();
```

Comment: `ytplayer.seekTo(42);` to jump to the 42th second.